Local freeness of dualizing sheaf
I am reading the dualizing sheaf and duality theorems from Hartshorne’s algebraic geometry book. I am wondering about the following.
When does the dualizing sheaf of a projective scheme is an locally free sheaf?
I know that for non singular projective scheme dualizing sheaf is isomorphic o the canonical sheaf, hence it is locally free. But does there exists any condition on the scheme when it is locally free.
Can anyone provide any example when dualizing sheaf is not locally free?
Thanks in advance.

This is equivalent to the scheme being Gorenstein. I suggest that you read an introductory book on Grothendieck duality (Hartshorne's Residues and duality comes to mind) rather than asking questions here.
